# ASP irc bot drops after 20 minutes

Tags: asp.net, bots, irc

I'm trying to make an IRC bot with ASP. I have established connection to IRC server and everything works fine, but after 20 minutes the connection just breaks... I have tried adding following lines to web.config file:

```
<sessionState timeout="60"/> 
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="32678"/>
```

but it didn't work. I was wondering if it might be because of my host, but I don't want to move to another one until I am certain this problem can be solved... I would hate to have to rewrite it in php or some other language. Any help would be appreciated.

Solved it by telling people to open the app every 15 minutes, so the bot now hangs indefinitely. Not an elegant solution but it works :)

Comment: Are you definately using Classic ASP and not ASP.NET, as the web.config changes are for ASP.NET? If you are using Classic ASP then it might help to show the code you are using for your connection.

Comment: Yes it is ASP.NET, that autocomplete tricked me :) tnx for the tip...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your app pool simply shutting itself down due to 20 minutes of inactivity? (which is the default value on IIS)

Comment: It's probably that. I'm kind of new with ASP so I didn't know about that. Do you know if paid hosting providers allow for that time to be extended, or is there some way of making my application not timing out?